# How does Python Compiler and Virtual Machine handle eval expressions?

Tags: python, compilation, interpreter

Lets suppose I have a code in **Python** and in the middle of this code I have an `eval` expression which depends on some external input, for example:

```
exp = raw_input() 
eval(exp)
```

My question is: which mechanism Python's compiler and interpreter use to bind the code which can be compiled with the code that depends on a runtime value?

Comment: Since Python is interpreted, it can call its own compiler/interpreter from `eval()`.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that a Python code passes through a compilation stage before it's execution in the python virtual machine. My question is: how does this pre-compilation works in cases like this which depends on a expression provided in execution time? Is the coded compiled and the dependent part binded compiled and binded by the interpreter in time of execution?

Comment: The compiler is called by `eval()`.

Comment: The compiler doesn't only run before execution. If you use `import`, it has to compile the file you're importing from. `eval()` is similar, it just gets the code to compile from a variable instead of a file.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you! Consider adding the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python compiler doesn't care where the code it's compiling comes from. It can compile code that comes from a file before execution when you run `python filename`, it can compile files during execution when you use `import`, and it can compile code from a string expression when you call `eval()` or `exec()`. These functions invoke the compiler dynamically.